# Create Bundle Product Programatically and Assign Simple Products

Tags: magento2.3

I am using Magento 2.3.*  and I want to create a Bundle Product and Associate the simple products using code.

Comment: thanks @MuhammadHasham

Comment: Yeah Sure @MuhammadHasham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating a product with type bundled we have to add a link and option information for the product.

These are modified attribute as compare to simple product creation

```
 $product->setTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_BUNDLE); 
 $product->setPriceType(1); 
 $product->setPriceView(1);
```

To add a link use the below code.

```
$link = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Bundle\Api\Data\LinkInterface::class);
$link->setPosition(0);
$link->setSku('MH01-XS-Orange');
$link->setIsDefault(false);
$link->getQty(1);
$link->setPrice(12);
$link->setPriceType(\Magento\Bundle\Api\Data\LinkInterface::PRICE_TYPE_FIXED);
```

To add link to option add below code:

```
$optionRepository = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Bundle\Api\ProductOptionRepositoryInterface::class);
$option = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Bundle\Api\Data\OptionInterface::class);
$option->setTitle('Size');
$option->setType('radio');
$option->setRequired(true);
$option->setPosition(1);
$option->setProductLinks(array($link));
$optionRepository->save($product, $option);
```

Reference: http://www.w3solver.com/magento-2-add-a-bundled-product-programmatically/